# Script executed on remote server using Python Paramiko cannot read/access local files

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, vps

I'm trying to run a local Python script from my laptop (which works fine) on remote server (VPS).

The script can't read local files from my laptop from VPS
Output:

[image: Output of the script who runs the script remotely. Output of the code below]

My script on pycharm.

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko

# Connect to remote host
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('myip', port=22, username='root', password='mypassword')

# Setup sftp connection and transmit this script
sftp = client.open_sftp()
sftp.put(r'/myscript.py', '/myscript.py')
sftp.close()
# till now everything's good. I check my VPS files i find my script uploaded there 

# Run the transmitted script remotely without args and show its output.
# SSHClient.exec_command() returns the tuple (stdin,stdout,stderr)
stdout = client.exec_command('python3 /myscript.py')[1]
for line in stdout:
    # Process each line in the remote output
    print(line)

client.close()
sys.exit(0)
```

When I run script from VPS I got this issue

I can't run the script directly from VPS to check the issue because I use local files, check the screenshot:

[image: Run from VPS]

When I remove local paths and run the script (both from pycharm and VPS), it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot magically access local files from script run on a server.

> I can't run the script directly from VPS to check the issue because i use local files, check img.

There's no difference between running the script in remote shell using your favourite SSH terminal client (I assume that's what you mean by *"run the script directly from VPS"*) and running the script in remote shell using Paramiko. It still runs in the remote shell.

---

There's no easy way to make the client files accessible from the server. That would be a security nightmare.

- Either your script has to upload the files to the server.
- Or you need to run a (SFTP/FTP/whatever) server on your local machine to make your local file accessible to the world.

  For an example how to run an SFTP server, see my guide:
  [Installing SFTP/SSH server on Windows using OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)